# after alter system flush shared_pool low performance Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, system, flush, alter

We did refactoring and replaced 2 similar requests with parameterized request

a.isGood = :1

after that request that used this parameter with parameter 'Y' was executed longer that usually (become almost the same with parameter 'N'). We used alter system flush shared_pool command and request for parameter 'Y' has completed fast (as before refactoring) while request with parameter 'N' hangs for a long time.

As you could understand number of lines in data base with parameter 'N' much more then with 'Y'

Oracle 10g

Why it happened?

Comment: did you run an Oracle trace on the session and tkprof?  Nobody here can speculate without empirical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have an index on that column, otherwise the performance would be the same regardless of the Y/N combination. I have seen this happening quite bit on 10g+ due to Oracle's optimizer **Bind Peeking** combined to **histograms** on columns with skewed data distribution. The histograms get created automatically when one gathers tables statistics using the parameter method_opt with 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO' (among other values). Oracle optimizes the query for the value in the bind variables **provided in the very first execution** of that query. If you run the query with Y the first time, Oracle might want to use an index instead of a full table scan, since Y will return a small quantity of rows. The next time you run the query with N, then Oracle will repeat the first execution plan, which happens to be a poor choice for N, since it will return the vast majority of rows.

The execution plans are cached in the SGA. Once you flush it, you get a brand new execution plan the very first time the query runs again.

My suggestion is:

- Obtain the explain plan of both original queries (one with a hardcoded Y and one with a hardcode N). Investigate if the two plans use different indexes or one has a much higher Cost than the other. I have the feeling that one uses a full table scan and the other uses an index. The first one should be faster for N and the second should be faster for Y.
- Try to remove the statistics on the table and see if it makes a difference on the query that has the bind variable. Later you need to gather statistics again for the table or other queries on that table might suffer.

  - You can also gather statistics for that one table using method_opt => FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1. That will keep the statistics without the histograms on any columns of that table.
- A bitmap index on this column might fix the issue as well. Indexes on a column that have only two possible values (Y and N) are not exactly very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If column `isGood` has 99,000 'N' values and 1,000 'Y' values and you run with the condition `isGood = 'Y'`, then it may be appropriate to use an index to find the results: you are returning 1% of the rows.  If you run the query with the condition `isGood = 'N'`, a full table scan would be more appropriate since you are returning most of the table anyway.  If you were to use an index for the `N` condition, you would be doing an extra index lookup for every data item lookup.

Although the general rule is that bind parameters are good, it can be problematic in this kind of instance if really two different plans are required for the query.  With the bind parameter scenario:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE isGood = :1
```

The statement will be parsed and a plan computed and saved in the sql cache.  The same plan will be used for both query scenarios which is not desirable.  But:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE isGood = 'Y'
SELECT * FROM x WHERE isGood = 'N'
```

will result in two plans being stored in the sql cache, hopefully each with the appropriate plan for the query.  Version 11g avoids this problem with [adaptive cursor sharing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#PFGRF95174), which can use different plans for different bind variable values.

You need to look at your plans (`EXPLAIN PLAN`) to see what is happening in your case. Flush the cache, try one method, examine the plan; try the other, examine the plan.  It might give you an idea what is happening in your case.  There are a bunch of other topics you might follow up on that may help, for example:

- using a hint to force the use of an index
- cursor_sharing parameter
- histograms on statistics